# MVC5 Razor View jQuery DataTables pagination checked items with EditorFor

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, datatables

I have a problem using datables with MVC5. I use datatbales to show and select items.

The whole thing works fine except that when I try to select all records and there are more pages only the first page is selected. Another problem is that if I select 3 items from page 1 and 2 items from page 2, when I post my selection no items are posted.

Here is my attempt:

```
@model Project.Models.Demo


@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "rform", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()  

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="elementstable">
   <thead>
       <tr role="row">
       <th>
          <label>
                 <input type="checkbox">
                 <span class="text"></span>
          </label>
       </th>
       <th>
           @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
       </th>
       <th>
           @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)
       </th>
       <th>
           @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Created)
       </th>

       </tr>
    </thead>

<tbody>
       @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Items)
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the EditorFor partial view: `model.Items` is a `List<Item>`

```
@model Project.Model.Item

<tr>
    <td>
        <label>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsSelected)
            <span class="text"></span>
        </label>

    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ItemId)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Address)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Address)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Created)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Created)
    </td>
</tr>
```

And here is the form:

```
             @Html.Bootstrap().SubmitButton().Text("Save").Color(BootstrapColors.Success).IconPrepend(FontAwesome.Check).HtmlAttributes(new { id = "ok" })   
}


@section PageScripts{
<link href="~/assets/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/assets/js/datatable/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/js/datatable/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/js/datatable/dataTables.tableTools.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/js/datatable/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/js/datatable/datatables-init.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var oTable = $('#elementstable').dataTable({
            "sDom": "Tflt<'row DTTTFooter'<'col-sm-6'i><'col-sm-6'p>>",
            "aLengthMenu": [
              [ -1],
              [ "All"]
            ],
            "iDisplayLength": -1,
            "oTableTools": {
                "aButtons": []
            },
            "language": {
                "search": "",
                "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sPrevious": "Prev",
                    "sNext": "Next"
                }
            },
            "aoColumns": [
              { "bSortable": false, "width": '45px' },
              { "bSortable": false },
              { "bSortable": false },
              { "bSortable": false }
            ],
            "aaSorting": []
        });

        $('#elementstable thead th input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
            var set = $("#elementstable tbody tr input[type=checkbox]");
            var checked = $(this).is(":checked");
            $(set).each(function () {
                if (checked) {
                    $(this).prop("checked", true);
                    $(this).parents('tr').addClass("active");
                } else {
                    $(this).prop("checked", false);
                    $(this).parents('tr').removeClass("active");
                }
            });

        });
        $('#elementstable tbody tr input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
            $(this).parents('tr').toggleClass("active");
        });


</script>
}
```

As I mentioned, this works for one page at the time.

Problems:

- select all rows checkbox that will select all items from all pages not only the current page
- select individual rows
- select individual rows from different pages
- post all selected items (from current page and other pages) to the action as a List